# Is it desirable to clear STL vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

A quick question - possibly of style.
Is it desirable to clear/empty a vector when it's no longer required, or can you simply rely on STL to clean up after itself when a container is no longer required.

I'm talking in this case about basic vectors that don't contain pointers or other objects that require delete eg.

```
std::vector<double> myVector;
// use it
// finished with it
// use clear?
myVector.clear();
```

Comment: `std::vector<double,double>`?

Comment: Check your syntax. `vector<double>` is more like it unless you want a `vector<vector<double>>`.

Comment: woops sorry, copied a map definition - now corrected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to release std::vector if there is no heap memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925151/how-to-release-stdvector-if-there-is-no-heap-memory)

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253969/proper-vector-memory-managment for info on vector memory management too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no benefit to clearing a vector, since it's not guaranteed to give up its storage. See `capacity()`.

If you're really concerned about the memory used by the vector, you can use a little trick to substitute it with an empty vector:

```
std::vector<double>().swap(myVector);
```

Of course the easiest method is to just let the vector go out of scope and it will be destroyed automatically and all its storage will be freed.

Comment: Thanks Naveen, Bukes and Mark. I thought that might have been the case, but wanted to confirm it as it felt a bit 'un-lean'.

Comment: @GManNickG, it's still a bit early to assume everyone has access to C++11 features.

Comment: @MarkRansom: but it is worth mentionning as an alternative for those who do :)

Answer (score 3):

When the vector object goes out of scope, the resources associated with it will be recovered.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to call `clear`, `vector` will handle it itself. Use `clear` only when you want to use that object again but want to remove all its contents.